# I dropped my tissue box on a glass table, the box didn't bounce back, table didn't move nor break, what happened?

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, work

I have a box, it drops and thus by moving has Kinetic energy, It doesn't penetrate and impacts however the box doesn't rebound nor breaks the table. Its like when I slam my fist on a table but the table doesn't break, I don't hold it there and my hand doesn't bounce back.

If it falls, its in motion and gaining velocity every second, so when it hits it has Kinetic energy, the ability to do work. I know the energy isn't enough to break it but my box doesn't bounce back.

The box didn't bounce back because the box transfer its energy into the table, it exerted a force on the table from its impact correct? The table did vibrate a little, so would this be true? The box exerts a force on the table but only for a little bit? Its absorbed by the table, even though the force did compress the table, the force from the impact of the box.

Also, it vibrates...(this is a dumb question I probably know the answer to but Im being careful...so it absorbs the impact, there is material that absorb the impact but it hard or rigid enough not the vibrate or keeps the vibration low and/or confined to a small area?

In short, the box's kinetic energy is converted into force for a little while before heat, thus impact force correct?

I took a wooden board and placed a toy car on the other side, I placed the board and made it stable. I hit the board with a hammer on the opposite side of the car, the hammer hit, it bounced a little, it accelerated the car, I did it again and I hit board with the hammer, not as hard, it didn't bounce but accelerated the car.

Thus, the hammer with Kinetic energy, didn't penetrate, it moved the car, it barely bounced back. thus did the hammer exerted force.

Okay, so we know it must exert force, the hammer exerts force, so how do I calculate time applied? I know Favg=KE/d equals force, as KE will exert force...but if the penetration distance is zero, then we must use momentum and change in momentum over time.

Favg= 2m*V / t right? which shows the force...but also shows the force the KE exerted on the object.

So, if my hammer is moving at 30m/s...it weighs 0.06 kg's..so 27 joules...it hits a wall, doesn't bounce off by any measurable amount, it deforms very little for a small while, so temporary....27Joules is turned into force, how do I find that force and its moving at 30m/s...what would it be?

Comment: You appear to be describing an inelastic collision, but I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: Well, its just my box doesn't bounce back, Im asking is my box producing force on the table with impact? and can some material stop vibrations(which that is a dumb question because Im 100% sure there is many materials that stop vibrations).

Comment: drop a lump of clay. It won't bounce either. Energy goes to deforming the box and contents.

Comment: but nothing is really getting deformed though...in this situation

Comment: @IBT98. "but nothing really getting deformed..." That's not true: both objects get deformed during the collision (a very small amount). Otherwise, there's no way to dissipate the energy that started out as the kinetic energy of the box.

Comment: okay, that is what I meant, so If I fired my bullet at a material that doesn't absorb the blast as well as Abrams armor, but like a plate of armor that might vibrate, if my bullet didn't penetrate, the armor didn't deform(by the naked eye) but the bullet shattered or rebounded....would it produce force from its KE?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: Okay, so like If placed a small car on the other side, it would accelerate, cool...so how would I calculate it...its about velocity right? Im not sure how but we could calculate it easily right?

Comment: Okay, so what would be the equation? If I had shot a bullet at a impenetrable wall which absorbs the impact, IF my bullet was rigid but not rigid enough so deformation occurs for a short time and is not visible by the naked human eye. If that bullet is moving at 300m/s and has 500J's of KE, that bullet doesn't bounce back after I hit the wall, so it transfers force from energy, that force is applied to that wall, how do I calculate that?

Comment: @march There *is* another way to dissipate heat, which is also by far the most common way: as a temperature rise! The materials heat up a tiny amount.

Comment: @Steeven. I don't agree. The process I described above *is* the process by which the temperature rises: the objects deform during the collision, and since different parts of the object are connected, the deformed part pulls on the parts surrounding it, which pull on the parts surrounding them, etc. and energy gets redistributed in that way, leading to larger average kinetic energy within the objects and hence higher temperature. You can't just say, "temperature goes up": you need to describe the *mechanism* by which the temperature increases, which is what I've done.

Comment: @march Aha, well if we are talking about temperature on the molecular level as the atomical motion, then of course, any kind of energy is kinetic.

Comment: @Steeven. The process I described is more general than just adding kinetic energy to the object. The solid could also *expand* due to nonlinearities in the intramolecular bonds, and so the *potential* energy can change as well. But anyway, that's beside the point: The objects *must* deform if the collision is inelastic (in order to conserve energy and momentum), and it is exactly this deformation that leads to dissipation of the initial kinetic energy (which eventually leads to a rise in temperature of the objects).

Comment: @IBT98 I have noticed that you are unfailingly coming back to calculating the force applied. The thing is, you may know the energy, the momentum, the velocity, mass etcetera of the moving object before it collides, you cannot calculate the average force exerted on impact, without knowing the period for which the collision occured. Plain and simple. You can know the time by either direct measurement or accurate knowledge of elastic properties of both colliding objects (perfectly elastic or inelastic is not enough).

Answer (score 1):

When your moving box collides with the table and comes to a complete stop, this kinetic energy is absorbed by the molecules making up the box and the table (see footnote as well). This increases the energy with which these molecules vibrate. The air molecules surrounding this table-box system will also vibrate because they are in contact with one of these objects.

Initially this vibration will appear to our senses as sound and eventually as heat (when the vibration becomes unordered or *random*).

In other words then, the box and the table collision has heated both of them and given you some rather good sound effects. Which one gets heated how much and what type of sound you hear (thud, ringing, etc.) depends on the actual materials involved here.

*Footnote: You can also argue that the table would also end up vibrating the floor (and eventually the building) but that amount of energy should be negligible compared to the amount absorbed by the air, table, and the box.*

Comment: Though the object doesn't penetrate, its Kinetic energy doesn't do work...it DOES however exert force, force needs energy, thus it loses energy thus exerting force, that force transfers to the molecules given them Kinetic energy, it they don't get displaced by the  force like a brick would when hit by a bullet( when a bullet hits a brick, the brick shatters)...thus the box produced force on the table even though no penetration, correct?

Comment: Yes. And that force is counteracted by the force the floor applies on the table. So the table remains motionless (on average).

Comment: So, If my box has 500 Joules of KE, would be the force?

Comment: Force is numerically hard to compute in these cases as you will have to figure out in how much time exactly did the box come to rest. Without that knowledge you are in the dark. Energy alone cannot give you that answer.

Comment: true, so my box when it hits is moving at 15m/s, the time lasts like what? 0.00001 seconds...or how would I calculate that? because it does produce a force, we have established that.

Comment: You have to measure time. Elasticities of the materials involved can help you predict that time but to be really accurate, you will have to measure it. High speed videos can help. Otherwise you can use a force sensor or an accelerometer to directly measure force and acceleration respectively. Also, I expect the time to stop to be of the order of 0.1 seconds.

Comment: Okay, we basically, If I throw a steel ball at a wall but the steel ball drops and wall isn't deformed....the steel ball does use its Kinetic energy to exert force on the wall even though its not doing work, it still exerts a force from the Kinetic Energy.

Comment: Okay, we basically, If I throw a steel ball at a wall but the steel ball drops and wall isn't deformed....the steel ball does use its Kinetic energy to exert force on the wall even though its not doing work, it still exerts a force from the Kinetic Energy

Comment: It sent 2, sorry.

Comment: One fine point:  when your steel ball bounces off of the wall, some work is done.  Both the ball and the wall deform slightly.  Most of the energy that that work delivers to the ball and wall is returned right back to the ball in the bounce: the objects are largely elastic.  But not entirely; some energy remains in the ball and wall as thermal energy (and radiated as acoustic energy).

Comment: Okay, but I said the steel ball doesn't bounce back, it hits the wall and stops....but what if the wall doesn't deform, like its made of tank armors or such. Im also thinking, If I shot a bullet into that wall, the bullet shatters...but it does exert a force in that wall right? So If I put my hand behind that wall when the bullet impacts, will I feel the impact force(if this is not ultra dense to which it absorbs the impact and stops the vibration)...but lets say this is not that material, so would I feel the impact force?

Comment: If the wall didn't deform, then the steel ball would bounce back. Something has to deform, and steel is springy. It's only if the wall does deform, and then fails to bounce back, that the ball will stop. If the ball stops it must be an 'inelastic' collision, meaning the energy is dissipated.

Answer (score -2):

The table in which you are dropping something is a rigid, fixed object. In turn, the energy is being converted to moving the whole earth and the rigid object in which the earth is supporting (even though it would move an infinitesimally small amount).

This is similar to jumping. The equal action-reaction pair is simply the earth, and yourself.

Comment: This analysis does not conserve energy.  The OPs situation is inelastic.

Comment: wait, the Kinetic energy MUST exert a force on impact....